# What does user "has_extended_profile" mean? Return from the twitter API

Tags: json, api, twitter

One of the user attributes in the twitter API says "has_extended_profile". What does this say about a twitter user?

I know this is no longer supported but I have an old dataset

Comment: This is irrelevant data. It was related to attributes that were never exposed in standard Twitter profiles, and is now deprecated.

Comment: also, note that you should not be storing Twitter data on a long-term basis. Pay attention to I.C.3 of the [developer policy](https://developer.twitter.com/en/developer-terms/policy.html)